# Norm on $\mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: real-analysis, normed-spaces

I have a question about if this $|(x_1,x_2)|=\sqrt{\dfrac{x_1^2}{9}+4x_1^2}$ function is a norm, I know the first two statements are done but the triangular inequality  is not clear for me, so I started with let $(x_1,x_2),(y_1,y_2) \in \mathbb{R}^2$

$
|(x_1,x_2)+(y_1,y_2)|=\sqrt{\dfrac{(x_1+y_1)^2}{9}+4(x_2+y_2)^2}=\sqrt{(\dfrac{x_1}{3}+\dfrac{y_1}{3})^2+(2x_2+2y_2)^2}=\sqrt{u+v+\dfrac{2x_1y_1}{3}+8x_2y_2}
$

in this case if $x_1,y_1,x_2,y_2>0$ we have by Minkowski inequality
$\sqrt{u+v+\dfrac{2x_1y_1}{3}+8x_2y_2}\leq\sqrt{u+v}\leq\sqrt{u}+\sqrt{v}$.Where $u=\dfrac{x_1^2}{9}+4x_2^2$ and $v=\dfrac{y_1^2}{9}+4y_2^2$

But in the other case, I don't know how to prove it. thx for any help here

Comment: One of the $x_1$ is $x_2$?

Comment: You went one step too far. Go back to $\sqrt{(\dfrac{x_1}{3}+\dfrac{y_1}{3})^2+(2x_2+2y_2)^2}$ and write it in the form $\sqrt{u^2 + v^2}$ then apply the triangle inequality to $u$ and $v$. Rearrange the resulting expression to prove the claim.

Answer (score 1):

Let the *usual Euclidean norm* of $p$ as $N(p)$, then your norm is just $|(x,y)|=N(\frac x3,2y)$. Let linear map $L$ as $L(x,y)=(\frac x3,2y)$, then $|(x,y)|=(N\circ L)(x,y)$.

So...

$$
|p+q|=(N\circ L)(p+q)=N(Lp+Lq)\le(N\circ L)(p)+(N\circ L)(q)=|p|+|q|
$$

That means, the triangle inequality holds of your norm $|\cdot|$.